# wxPython crashes under Vista

Tags: python, windows-vista, wxpython

I am following the [Getting Started](http://wiki.wxpython.org/Getting%20Started) guide for wxPython. But unfortunately the [first 'Hello World' example](http://wiki.wxpython.org/Getting%20Started#head-6e8427493dcc765fb873a1838adfbd6b8d08e0ee) crashes. The dialog window shows just fine, but as soon as I move my mouse over the window a "pythonw.exe has stopped working" Windows message appears.

I use:

- Python 2.6.2
- [wxPython2.8-win32-unicode-2.8.9.2-py26](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/wxpython/wxPython2.8-win32-unicode-2.8.9.2-py26.exe)
- Vista (latest SP and updates installed) 32 bits, running as Admin

Any ideas what can be wrong, or how to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See here for why: http://www.tejerodgers.com/snippets/2009/why-wxpython-crashes-python-26/

See wxPython's README for a hack that will let you work around the problem.

A fix has been discovered and will be included in the next release.

Answer (score 2):

32 or 64 bit Vista? When you did installs did you "run as admin"? I also had some issues with permissions on vista early on.

Also, this may be a fix if it isn't just the installation problem.

http://www.python-forum.org/pythonforum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=11331

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thx, actually this answer is what helped me out: http://www.python-forum.org/pythonforum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=11331#p54621

Comment: Oh... and I added the info about Vista you asked for to the question